# Server is not Recognizing the json, sending request using restSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

i am trying to post some json to jboss services. using restSharp.. my code is as follows.

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient(baseURL);
        RestRequest authenticationrequest = new RestRequest();
        authenticationrequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        authenticationrequest.Method = Method.POST;
        authenticationrequest.AddParameter("text/json",                  authenticationrequest.JsonSerializer.Serialize(prequestObj), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

and also tried this one

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient(baseURL);
        RestRequest authenticationrequest = new RestRequest();
        authenticationrequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        authenticationrequest.Method = Method.POST;                           authenticationrequest.AddBody(authenticationrequest.JsonSerializer.Serialize(prequestObj));
```

but in both cases my server is giving me error that json is not in correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was going wrong...

i am using RestSharp in windows metro Style, so downloaded source code and make some modifications... so that modifications in the function PutPostInternalAsync i just added this modifications

```
 httpContent = new StringContent(Parameters[0].Value.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

and it solve the problem....

Parameters[0].Value.ToString() instead of this you can write a method which can return the serialize json object. (as string).

Answer (score 0):

Try using JsonHelper to prepare your json as the following

```
 string jsonToSend = JsonHelper.ToJson(prequestObj);
```

and then

```
authenticationrequest.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", jsonToSend, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: no success, when i checked the server log it is not getting the json string in the body..

Comment: Can you debug what is the value there in your prequestObj and what it becomes after ToJson

Comment: on client side json is in correct format, but on server side json value is empty